# How can i save image name into gallery with android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media?

Tags: android, camera

I already spent my 4 hours just try to solve this case. I have an image from my Imgaeview and i want to save it into gallery with diferent name, but the name its still the same.

**Method On SimpleWay**

```
public String StoringImage(Bitmap bitmap, String nameImage) {

    String savedImageURL = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            getContentResolver(),
            bitmap,
           nameImage + ".jpg",
            null
    );


    return savedImageURL;
}

public void OpenAlertDialog(Context context, final Bitmap bitmap, final 
TextView textView, String title){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    final EditText editText = new EditText(context);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setView(editText);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String name = editText.getText().toString();
            String textImge = StoringImage(bitmap, name);
            textView.setText(textImge);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}
```

**The listener that i used for CameraActivity**

```
  @Override
public void initListener() {
    bCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pickImage(CameraActivity.this, PICK_CAMERA);
            imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    bChooseFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pickImage(CameraActivity.this, PICK_GALLERY);
        }
    });
    bCitra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap = takeBitmap(imageView);
            OpenAlertDialog(CameraActivity.this, bitmap, textView, "Input");
        }
    });
    bGray.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap grayBitmap = openCVConverter.ConverToGray(takeBitmap(imageView));
            setBitmap(grayBitmap);
        }
    });
    bBinary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap binaryBitmap = openCVConverter.RGBImageToBinary(takeBitmap(imageView));
            setBitmap(binaryBitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

this is the image when i already save it but the name is still the same.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not clear which name is always the same. Is it the *nameImage* parameter?

Comment: i input newimage on alertdialog and the one got saved its diferent name with number